# How to fix ML Kit loading problem? - Failed to scan code

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

Error on Scan UI loading: "com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Failed to scan code."

I have a problem with my device.
When the Scan UI is loading (on GmsBarcodeScanning) i'm getting exception addOnFailureListener. "com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Failed to scan code."
In other devices i cannot get the same bug... but more than one for sure.
Some one have any workaround to fix it? Tnk

Platform: Android
Project: com.google.mlkit.samples.codescanner

Comment: I have the same issue on some devices. I've [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261579118) it in Google's Issue Tracker.

Comment: This is likely because of the scanner module is not downloaded yet. Can you check whether it's the case by using ModuleInstallClient API?
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/code-scanner#configure_your_app

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround.

Always send an install request. If the barcode scanner module is already installed it will not be installed again.

[Send an urgent module install request](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/module-install-apis?hl=en#send_an_urgent_module_install_request)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val moduleInstall = ModuleInstall.getClient(this)
    val moduleInstallRequest = ModuleInstallRequest.newBuilder()
            .addApi(GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this))
            .build()
    moduleInstall
        .installModules(moduleInstallRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it.areModulesAlreadyInstalled()) {
                // Modules are already installed when the request is sent.
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            // Handle failure…
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the storage data in the google play services app (Settings > Apps > Google Play Service > Storage) and try to update the google play services app. It solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Change metadata value from "barcode_ui" to "barcode" in the AndroidManifest.xml

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/code-scanner?hl=en

says that

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
      android:value="barcode_ui"/>
```

This caused problem.

As stated in this link
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android?hl=en

You must use

```
<meta-data
          android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
          android:value="barcode" >
```